# Embed Form and EntityType to select the associated entity in Embed Form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a slight problem and I can't find a solution to solve it, I had to miss a step or a method, here is the context:

I have a Registration entity linked to an establishment (a registration is linked to a single establishment)

In my form, the first field allows me to select the establishment with select, then other fields linked to the establishment, such as its participation or not, but already displayed:

Here's what it looks like:

```
Establishment: <select>
Participates: Yes / No
AdditionalInfo: Textarea
```

With this form, I therefore wish to recover during the submission, a Registration entity with the selected Establishment and also the fields with the correct values in the Establishment

I tried in the RegistrationType to put:

```
$builder
    ->add('establishment', EstablishmentType::class)
;
```

And in EstablishmentType:

```
$builder
    ->add('id', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => Establishment::class,
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'query_builder' => function (EstablishmentRepository $repository) {
            return $repository->findAllQueryBuilder($user);
        },
    ])
    ->add('participate', ChoiceType::class, [
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => false,
        'choices' => [
            'front.form.establishment.participate.yes' => true,
            'front.form.establishment.participate.no' => false,
        ],
    ])
    ->add('comment', TextAreaType::class)
    ;
```

But without more astonishment, it does not work, he tries to set an Establishment and not the id of the establishment, which is rather logical ...

Do you have any ideas for doing this? an unmapped field in the RegistrationType that allows you to properly map the establishment? Any other ideas? Need more info?

Comment: You can use a [Data Transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html) for this. If you still need help after reading the Doc, please comment, ill come back then...

Comment: I thought about that, so I added the DataTransofmer on the id in EstablishmentType, in the transform, if I have an Establishment, I return its id, no problem, in the reverse, I have my correct entity.
During the submission and that I check what I have in $registration-> getEstablishement(), the Establishment entity is empty ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, I could not use DataTransformer because my entity was being overwritten, so I add a PreSubmit listener to set my establishment with the correct entity recovered from the DB.

Here is the listener added in `RegistrationType`:

```
/** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
$em = $this->entityManager;

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (PreSubmitEvent $event) use ($em) {
    $data = $event->getData();

    $id = isset($data['establishment']) && isset($data['establishment']['id']) ? $data['establishment']['id'] : null ;

    if(!empty($id)){
        $establishment = $em->getRepository(Establishment::class)->find($id);
        $event->getForm()->get('establishment')->setData($establishment);
    }
});
```

There are certainly improvements to be made to the code or another method, in any case, this one has just unlocked me!